# Make a single Table Header in align center

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to make full align in center as it is only a single item in header , it should be like center heading in table

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <th>Full</th>



  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Pass</th>
    <th>Fail</th>
    <th>Error</th>
    <th>Skip</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Use the `colspan` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `colspan` attribute on the `<th>` element. You should also wrap your `<tr>` (rows) that contain `<th>` (header) elements in a `<thead>` tag.

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5">Full</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Pass</th>
      <th>Fail</th>
      <th>Error</th>
      <th>Skip</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Content here -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks Polywhirl  just what i was looking for

Comment: Your `colspan` value is off by one.

Comment: @user1438038 I guess I can't math (count) this morning. I need more coffee.